# Get Image Data in in PHP or Laravel From URL

Tags: php, html, laravel, file, multipartform-data

I want to read file data especially image file but, the image is already uploaded in somewhere or server directory, not from input html. How can I get this? Thank you

ex

`$url = 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/805651234698842112/uPSrYOHT.jpg'`

I want to get that file data **same** as with $_FILES post from input html.

Comment: you mean you are trying to upload image from another website to your website?

Comment: This can be straightforward using even just `file_get_contents` to get file data from your server or from outside (other online website). Some servers may block automated queries identifying themselves with popular bot names. Setting the appropriate user agent may be required, and in extreme cases programmatic retrieval may not even be possible if servers check browser integrity before returning the resource.

Comment: @ArvinJasonCabrera that's right, because we have different server in our company, and want to pass image ID Card to another server. I still don't know what to do, so alternatively, I add button download ID Card to my form in the first server, so our admin can download it and re-input it to send it to our second server

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function:

```
function download($url, $outputPath)
{
    set_time_limit(0);
    $fp = fopen($outputPath, 'w+');
    $ch = curl_init(str_replace(' ', '%20', $url));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

If you want to get the contents instead of storing into a file, you can use this function:

```
function download($url)
{
    set_time_limit(0);
    $ch = curl_init(str_replace(' ', '%20', $url));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Can we have variable result that contains image data and send it another server?

Comment: Of course. I've edited the answer to cover this need.

Comment: �SWQ2� N4}sj�_��������� /1|�\Z��`!�cօ� ����b�?j{\�s�R��L�B&����۽W�U��}�O���p�p��4 ��M�<�+�� " .jpeg, it showed this. It means I can save this data to variable and post it with curl to my other server?

Comment: Yes, this is the real content of the image file.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code you might get all the necessary data.

```
<?php

// Your code here!
$url = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/805651234698842112/uPSrYOHT.jpg";
$temp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'TMP_');
echo $temp; // output => C:\Windows\Temp\TMP2142.tmp

file_put_contents($temp, file_get_contents($url));

$content = file_get_contents($temp);

$size = getimagesize($temp);
$extension = image_type_to_extension($size[2]);
echo $content;
echo "<br>";
echo print_r($size); // output => Array ( [0] => 120 [1] => 120 [2] => 3 [3] => width="120" height="120" [bits] => 4 [mime] => image/png )

echo "<br>";
echo $extension; // output => .png
```

Comment: I havent try it but i'll try, hope it works. Thank you very much

Comment: �SWQ2� N4}sj�_��������� /1|�\Z��`!�cօ� ����b�?j{\�s�R��L�B&����۽W�U��}�O���p�p��4 ��M�<�+�� "
.jpeg, it showed this. It means I save this data to variable and post it with curl to my other server?

Comment: Yes. it's file content. You should store this into your final file.

Comment: @FGtaV if you find my answer helpful than you can approve and vote my answer.it will encourage me to help others.